# Why are the corners rounded?

Tags: html, css

I have a section of a site I'm creating where blog posts go, but for some reason the corners on where the content is displayed are rounded. I don't know what the problem could be. I've tried editing the border and padding but the corners are still rounded. Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XQjf/) of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

These three lines of code cause the rounded corners. Remove them if you don't want rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the borer-radius from your css:

```
.topcontent {
    background-color:#EBEBEB;
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... You do have `border-radius: 5px;` set... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Both CSS class declarations contain this ominous snippet. ;)

```
border-radius: 5px;
```